# After Remove Hyper Pay Can Not Run Project

Tags: flutter

## Can Not Run Project

The Project not run emulator or real device after trying to remove "Hyper_pay" plugin

#### Error :

```
Could not find :oppwa.mobile-release:
```

Answer (score 0):

## HOW TO FIX oppwa.mobile-release ?

### Navigate to gradle and remove

```
implementation (name:'oppwa.mobile-4.5.0-release', ext:'aar')
```

### Do This Step when you need to remove plugin Hyper_pay

https://github.com/nyartech/hyperpay